# A tool to store knowledge (mostly links with some notes) in a tree-like structure?

Tags: note-taking, bookmark, knowledge-organization, knowledge-base

Right now I use bookmarks as a way to store all useful websites, libraries, programming tools, lectures. And that works OK, but lacks some useful features.
I have them nested i.e., "Programming → Java → Libraries → GSON library link". But if I want to add some notes to the link, I'm out of luck.

Other features I'm looking for:

- Ability to tag links and search by tag
- Store one link in multiple locations of the tree
- HTML export
- Full-text search of all data

Is there a tool that I can use for a knowledge-base like this?

I'm using Windows 7, but I prefer a web-based solution. It can be a website or a Chrome app. I'm good with self-hosted tools but prefer if it's hosted by someone.

Comment: Since you already have a lot of info in your bookmarks, I would search for an add-on that lets you add notes to bookmarks. Note that storing one link in multiple locations of the tree is already possible in e.g. Firefox - not with 'Add link', but by copying a link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[OneNote](http://www.onenote.com/) sounds close to what you want.

- deep hierarchy support (limited by length of the path)
- now [free to download](http://www.onenote.com/download) on Windows and Mac
- view on web via http://www.onenote.com/
- Android, Chrome, iOS, WP7 apps
- you can tag items and get a summary (and customise the tags)
- full text search including images that contain text
- export to Word, PDF, and [MHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) (which I've never used before, but Chrome and Firefox surprisingly support)
- hotkey to store a quick note / screenshot
- web clipping [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/onenote-clipper/gojbdfnpnhogfdgjbigejoaolejmgdhk?hl=en)

[image: OneNote]

Comment: That is unexpected! I will evaluate :D

Comment: It's the closest thing to what I imagined. Thank you.

Comment: My biggest gripe with OneNote during my school days (when I could have used it the most) was that it wasn't free and only on PC. Such is not the case anymore, I really like their direction!

Answer (score 2):

[Diigo](http://diigo.com) is a social bookmarking website which allows signed-up users to bookmark and tag web-pages. Additionally, it allows users to highlight any part of a webpage and attach sticky notes to specific highlights or to a whole page. You can use lists and tags to structure your online library.

See [diigo tools](https://www.diigo.com/tools). I like it's [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oojbgadfejifecebmdnhhkbhdjaphole).

The free [plan](https://www.diigo.com/premium) has unlimited bookmark/notes, and 500 highlights per year.

Comment: Does diigo support trees structure?

Answer (score 1):

[Dokuwiki] is a great choice for a knowledge base, since it feels much less bloated and syntax-y than Mediawiki for me. Features are, among others, plugins (possible to be auto-updated), local hosting on a portable pendrive install, media management, namespaces...

Tag management can be added via [tag plugin](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:tag).

Answer (score 0):

You could give [Evernote](https://www.evernote.com) a go - it is a web & multi platform app that allows you to make notes, including web pages, and links.  There are plug-ins for various browsers that allow you to add any given page to your notes.

You can organise your notes but the full text search is a premium facility.

Comment: There is no tree-like structure deeper then 2 levels in Evernote that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Try [KwikText](http://kwiktext.com/). It lets you save links, notes, etc. in an editable tree structure, called Templates. You can create as many Templates as you like. All Templates are  saved (in an outline format that corresponds to the tree structure) as plain text. You can search templates using symbols for Boolean AND and NOT. You can drag web page links and other material directly into a Template.

KwikText is a free program for Windows computers. The website has videos that show how to use it.

Comment: Am I able to share kwiktext links?